# JSS Set RGB backgroundColor

Tags: reactjs, jss

If I have an RGB value that's fetched by a redux state, how can I use those values to set the background color of an element with JSS?

```
let color = {
     r: 255,
     g: 255,
     b: 0,
}

<div style={color}>asdf</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an object with CSS with key as css attribute name and value as shown below.

*Remember that object name can't contain dashes so you need to camelCase properties such as `background-color` into `backgroundColor`*

### Working Demo on CodeSandBox

[image: Edit soanswer51604710]

```js
let style = {
 color: "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
 backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 255, 0)"
}

class TodoApp extends React.Component {
 
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={style}>asdf</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

If you were to use [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/), you can copy & paste CSS as it is.

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Content = styled.div`
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
`

class TodoApp extends React.Component {
 
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Content>asdf</Content>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```